# Hyperledger Fabric: Error creating channelconfig bundle

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am trying to run a multi peer blockchain network using Hyperledger Fabric. My network has three peers. 
Here is the configtx.yaml file:

```
Profiles:

ComposerOrdererGenesis:
    Orderer:
        <<: *OrdererDefaults
        Organizations:
            - *OrdererOrg
    Consortiums:
        ComposerConsortium:
            Organizations:
                - *ManufacturerOrg
                - *CustomerOrg
                - *RegulatorOrg
ComposerChannel:
    Consortium: ComposerConsortium
    Application:
        <<: *ApplicationDefaults
        Organizations:
            - *ManufacturerOrg
            - *CustomerOrg
            - *RegulatorOrg


Organizations:


- &OrdererOrg

    Name: OrdererOrg
    ID: OrdererMSP


    MSPDir: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/Orderer-org/msp



- &ManufacturerOrg

    Name: ManufacturerOrg


    ID: ManufacturerOrgMSP

    MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/Manufacturer-org/msp

    # turn off security for the peer
    #AdminPrincipal: Role.MEMBER

    AnchorPeers:

        - Host: manufacturer-peer
          Port: 7051
- &CustomerOrg

    Name: CustomerOrg


    ID: CustomerOrgMSP

    MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/Customer-org/msp

    # turn off security for the peer
    AdminPrincipal: Role.MEMBER

    AnchorPeers:

        - Host: customer-peer
          Port: 7051
- &RegulatorOrg

    Name: RegulatorOrg


    ID: RegulatorOrgMSP

    MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/Regulator-org/msp

    # turn off security for the peer
    AdminPrincipal: Role.MEMBER

    AnchorPeers:

        - Host: regulator-peer
          Port: 7051


Orderer: &OrdererDefaults

# Orderer Type: The orderer implementation to start
# Available types are "solo" and "kafka"
OrdererType: solo

Addresses:
    - orderer.example.com:7050


BatchTimeout: 2s


BatchSize:

    MaxMessageCount: 10


    AbsoluteMaxBytes: 98 MB


    PreferredMaxBytes: 512 KB


Organizations:


Application: &ApplicationDefaults


Organizations:
```

After building the network through docker-compose, the orderer container exits with the following error in its log file,

> 2018-07-23 05:02:12.544 UTC [orderer/commmon/multichannel] newLedgerResources -> CRIT 086 Error creating channelconfig bundle: initializing configtx manager failed: bad channel ID: channel ID 'ComposerChannel' contains illegal characters
>   panic: Error creating channelconfig bundle: initializing configtx manager failed: bad channel ID: channel ID 'ComposerChannel' contains illegal characters

It says channel ID 'ComposerChannel' contains illegal characters. Please help me understand what that means. 
I'm pretty sure that there are no illegal characters in the configtx.yaml file while defining the channel

Comment: Can you check if there is any tab present in yaml file. It does not support tab instead use space to move forward or backward

Comment: That is a good catch! I will check it out.

Comment: Do you find any solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Channel ID can only contain lower-case alphanumeric characters and dashes.